# android run code when notification only

Tags: android, background, notifications

I have to know what is the mode name when the activity only shows in the Notification bar?
Also I want to know how to run a code in background like when there is only a notification icon or when the app is destroyed.I know it works with a Service,but I can't understand where to write the code that I want to run in background.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Write your code in Service.

Answer (score 0):

Use this article to understand notification:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html
Instead of Activity you can just use Service.